# Making ng-disabled true inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that is inside ng-repeat  which I need to enable only if I select the required field(Here in this case `<select>` drop down).But unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working.Can anybody suggest a possible fix for this.

```
<form name="myForm">    
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        <select ng-model="name" required ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in list">
            <option value="">--Select---</option>
        </select>    
        <button class="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Save</button>
    </div>    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-form` directive, here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>  
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">

        <ng-form name="testForm">
            <select ng-model="name" required ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in list">
            <option value="">--Select---</option>
            </select>    
            <button class="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="testForm.$invalid">Save</button>
         </ng-form>

    </div>    
</form>
```

here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xJBHCZb3eFKX9fxnnoeX?p=preview)

here is a [good explanation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're form is inside `ng-repeat` you'll have multiple forms binded to `$scope` with name `myForm` ( overwritten )

You should add different name for each form inside `ng-repeat`

Example :

```
<form name="myForm{{$index}}">
```

And on your button :

```
 <button class="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm{{$index}}.$invalid">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be simpler if you add name for every select element, so that you can refer to field errors separately:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        <select ng-model="name" name="name{{$index}}" required ng-options="r.id as r.name for r in list">
            <option value="">--Select---</option>
        </select>
        <button class="button" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="myForm['name' + $index].$invalid">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/RVY39iMv3dy96Cuw4q6B?p=info